# Android use ShelockFragment instead of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the below code to switch between `Fragment`s without any issues:

```
private void showSelectedItem(int index) {
        Fragment mFragment = null;
        if (index == mLastMenuItemSelected)
            return;
        FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastViewFragment != null) {
            fts.remove(mLastViewFragment);
        }
        switch (index) {
            case SV.MIS_ShowAllSubjects:
                mFragment = new FragmentViewAllSubjects();
                fts.replace(R.id.SubjectViewFragment, mFragment);
                txtSelectedSlideTitle.setText(UC.getString(R.string.slide_menu_main));
                break;
        }
        fts.commit();
        mLastMenuItemSelected = index;
        mSlidingMenu.showContent(true);
        mLastViewFragment = mFragment;
    }
```

now I want to use `SherlockFragment` instead of `Fragment`, for have this change I'm create new `Fragment` as :

```
public class ActionbarTabsPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    }
}
```

and I want to change top code to below code to use and switch between `SherlockFragment`s:

```
private void showSelectedItem(int index) {
    SherlockFragmentActivity mFragment = null;
    if (index == mLastMenuItemSelected)
        return;
    FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (mLastViewFragment != null) {
        fts.remove(mLastViewFragment);
    }
    switch (index) {
        case SV.MIS_ShowAllSubjects:
            mFragment = new ActionbarTabsPager();
            fts.replace(R.id.SubjectViewFragment, mFragment);
            txtSelectedSlideTitle.setText(UC.getString(R.string.slide_menu_main));
            break;
    }
    fts.commit();
    mLastMenuItemSelected = index;
    mSlidingMenu.showContent(true);
    mLastViewFragment = mFragment;
}
```

but i get this error and i can not resolve that:

```
Error:(141, 29) java: incompatible types: ir.jaziire.Fragments.ActionbarTabsPager cannot be converted to com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
Error:(149, 29) java: incompatible types: com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment cannot be converted to com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
```

my problem lines is :

```
mFragment = new ActionbarTabsPager();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActionbarTabsPager` is extending `SherlockFragmentActivity`, not `SherlockFragment`. Change

```
public class ActionbarTabsPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
```

to

```
public class ActionbarTabsPager extends SherlockFragment {
```

and

```
SherlockFragmentActivity mFragment = null;
```

to

```
Fragment mFragment = null;
```